# Right-to-left shell brace expansion

Tags: zsh, brace-expansion

In zsh (and other shells), if I include an argument like (for example):

```
{a,b,c}{d,e,f}
```

brace expansion turns it into:

```
ad ae af bd be bf cd ce cf
```

For my purposes, the argument order is important, and I need the braces to expand right-to-left instead of left-to-right. That is, I want the expansion to be:

```
ad bd cd ae be ce af bf cf
```

Is there a way to control the order that multiple sets of braces are expanded? I'm looking for something that will work in any situation, not just with these arguments.

Comment: I assume you're not interested in more complex solutions involving loops or sorted output, right?

Comment: @terdon If there's no other way I suppose; I was hoping there was some trick to change the order of evaluation of brace expansion, but there probably isn't. Those arguments were just an example though, so something that only works for `{a,b,c}{d,e,f}` isn't very helpful

Comment: Yeah, I guessed as much. You might want to make that clear though to avoid answers based on sorting order.

Comment: See also [How to generate a list with brace expansion in specific order](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18015654)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine parameter expansion with brace expansion.

```
% foo=(d e f)
$ echo {a,b,c}${^foo}
ad bd cd ae be ce af bf cf
```

If you don't want to define `foo` separately (as seems likely), you can use the following:

```
$ echo {a,b,c}${^:-d e f}
ad bd cd ae be ce af bf cf
```

If you have the `rcexpandparam` option set, then you don't need the `^` in either example to enable this behavior.

(Note: while testing, I also had the `shwordsplit` option set. If you don't have it set, then try, for example `echo {a,b,c}${^=:-d e f}`. Moral of the story: almost anything is possible in `zsh`, but you have to make sure you are using the correct combination of options and syntax.)

Comment: You should use `print --  {a,b,c}${^=:-d e f}` as the main example, since when `split+glob` was turned off by default in `zsh`.

Answer (score 4):

In `zsh` you can use the `-C` *specified number of columns* argument to `print` like:

```
print $(print -C3 {a,b,c}{d,e,f})
```

...to get...

```
ad bd cd ae be ce af bf cf
```

...without the `$IFS` splitting the following:

```
print -C3 {a,b,c}{d,e,f}
```

...prints...

```
ad bd cd
ae be ce
af bf cf
```

...but you can do that *across before down* like...

```
print -aC3 {a,b,c}{d,e,f}
```

---

```
ad ae af
bd be bf
cd ce cf
```

...or...

```
print $(print -aC2 {foo,bar}{bad,baz})
```

---

```
foobad foobaz barbad barbaz
```

Comment: That produces the same output that MIchael is trying to avoid. He wants 1.1 2.1 3.1 and you are giving 1.1 1.2 1.3 (if that's clear).

Comment: @terdon - good point.

Comment: I am guessing (though not explicitly stated) that Michael is after the specific order of pairing. Your approach only works if the elements can be sorted alphabetically. What about getting `foobad foobaz barbad barbaz` from {foo,bar}{bad,baz}`?

Comment: @terdon - well, if that's what he's after then why not say so? and anyway, the columns can be paired any which way if you do the math.

Comment: @terdon So basically this answer works if you take out the across-before-down bit.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `foobad barbad barbad barbaz` as in the example in the OP.

Comment: @terdon - you moderators seem to make it a habit of saying what you don't mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can put number at the end of each element of second set and then sort on last character:

```
echo -e "\n"{a,b,c}{d1,e2,f3} | sort -k 1.3 | cut -c 1-2 | tr '\n' ' '
```

Even better would be to add numbers after some separator (space), to cut fields, not characters:

```
echo -e "\n"{a,b,c}{"d 1","e 2","f 3"} | sort -k 2n | cut -f 1 -d ' ' -s | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

In `fish` shell, you have that behavior by default, [since expansion in `fish` is performed right-to-left](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#combine):

```
$ fish -c 'echo {a,b,c}{d,e,f}'
ad bd cd ae be ce af bf cf
```